# Jwt authentication, authorization any request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt, authorization

I cloned this github project: *https://github.com/cornflourblue/dotnet-5-jwt-authentication-api*

So I have followed function to validate the jtw token and on a successful jwt validation it attach user to context:

```
private void attachUserToContext(HttpContext context, string token)
{
   try
   {
      //...
      var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
      var userId = jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "username").Value;

      // attach user to context on successful jwt validation
      context.Items["User"] = userId;
   }
   catch
   {
      // do nothing if jwt validation fails
      // user is not attached to context so request won't have access to secure routes
   }
}
```

So the `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var username = context.HttpContext.Items["User"];
        if (username == null)
        {
            // not logged in
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason it allows all requests, even requests without header information. If u need more information then just ask!

Comment: don't roll your own `Authorize` trait. use the built in mechanisms

Comment: @DanielA.White can u share me a link where I can find more about the "built in mechanisms"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why the Custom `AuthorizeAttribute` dont work but I set the same
query to test that `HttpContext.Items["User"]` is not null and now it work...:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("Select")]
public IActionResult Select()
{
   try
   {
      if (HttpContext.Items["User"] == null)
      {
         return Conflict(new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized });
      }
      return Ok(TestService.Select());
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return Conflict(ex);
   }
}
```